# How do I stop the countdown from overlapping one another?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the code:

```
import tkinter as Alarm
class test(Alarm.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Alarm.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.prompt = Alarm.Label(self, text="Enter seconds:", anchor="w")
        self.entry = Alarm.Entry(self)
        self.output = Alarm.Label(self, text="Start")
        self.submit = Alarm.Button(self, text="Submit", command = self.startTimer)
        self.prompt.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20)
        self.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.submit.pack(side="right")
    def countdown(self, s):
        if s==0:
            self.output.configure(text="Alarm!")
            return  
        self.output.configure(text=str(s))
        s -= 1
        self.output.after(1000, lambda: self.countdown(s))
    def startTimer(self):
        try:
            i = int(self.entry.get())
            self.countdown(i)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter whole digits only in all boxes")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Alarm.Tk()
    test(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

So for this code, it allows me to create a countdown timer. What I want to do is to make it so that if a countdown is already running, it will stop if another countdown is set.

Comment: You would need to save the return value of `.after()` somewhere, so that you can call `.after_cancel()` on it if another countdown is started.

Comment: How do I check if another countdown started?

Comment: The check would be that `startTimer()` has been called, and there's a saved `.after()` return value stored.

Comment: Oh ok, so it’s just what Miraj50 did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a very small hack to do that. I have a `check` variable initialized to `0`. When you press the Submit button, it will change to `1`. In the countdown function, you can check for its value and take appropriate action. Here is a demo.

```
import tkinter as Alarm

class test(Alarm.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Alarm.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.prompt = Alarm.Label(self, text="Enter seconds:", anchor="w")
        self.entry = Alarm.Entry(self)
        self.output = Alarm.Label(self, text="Start")
        self.submit = Alarm.Button(self, text="Submit", command = self.startTimer)
        self.prompt.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=20)
        self.output.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=True)
        self.submit.pack(side="right")
        self.check = 0
    def countdown(self, s):
        if self.check == 0:
            return
        if s==0:
            self.output.configure(text="Alarm!")
            return  
        self.output.configure(text=str(s))
        s -= 1
        self.output.after(1000, lambda: self.countdown(s))
    def startTimer(self):
        self.check = (self.check+1)%2
        try:
            i = int(self.entry.get())
            self.countdown(i)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter whole digits only in all boxes")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Alarm.Tk()
    test(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: It worked really well with my actual code, thanks! :D